# Wordpress blank page after activating theme, but works in other server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to activate a Wordpress theme but all I got is a blank page, also the admin page goes blank.
Version of WP is 3.9.1, Mysql 5.1 compatible and PHP 5.2.4 compatible too with WP. The theme in question is MH Magazine and I have it in another server with the same configuration and is working ok.

Even I tried to do a backup of the working site and place it in the production server and still goes blank.
I tried uploading the max_memory_limit in php and no luck. Error log and show php errors doesnt show anything, when I check only says the site name HTTP 1.1 500 - If I set wp_debug to true says HTTP 1.1 200.
File permissions are ok too.

Comment: Hi find your main index.php file and at the very top just after the opening <?php tag add this line ini_set('display_errors', 1);  I suspect you are probably missing some dependencies ( functions ect.. ) on the one sever, then the other, also do you know if the php versions are the same with the same modules installed?

Comment: Yes are the same anyways the theme doesnt require any special module or config. I will try the display errors to see what happens.

Comment: @pmandell Op said they did that "I set wp_debug to true"

Comment: Also check if there is an error file in the same folder as the index.php page, there is for sure some kind of parser error, which is classically the blank page.

Comment: I did both things but nothing show still blank.

Comment: Ok try putting just echo "hello"; at the top of the page, if that doesn't show anything comment everything else out, that way we can make sure you are at least looking at the right page.  You have a .htaccess file in that folder too?

Comment: Check your apache error log please.

Comment: I tried all you said before but no luck. Even if I want to do a preview of the theme before activating it I get a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

**A SIMPLE FIX FOR NON TECHIES** (Like me really)

Loads of forums recommend various code changes and things to try, non of which worked, so I logically worked through the process more simply and solved it myself (in my case). White screen for everything, including front end and Admin. I tried everything going!

Essentially I'd asked Wordpress to link to a theme, which it did, but now I can't change it back. As it wouldn't automatically switch back to default themes, as suggested by others as a result of simply deleting the theme folder via ftp, I would have to force that myself. Without access to the admin panel, how would I change the link (easily)?. Well I can't, so instead I need to force the change of what it links to instead!

In the end I basically logged in via FTP, went to the wp-content folder, then to themes, located my list of theme folders and changed the theme folder name of the one recently selected and causing the issue, by just adding an x at the end (random letter). Then I changed the theme folder 'default' to the name of the theme which was causing the issue, then refreshed my site in the other window, at which point it displayed again. So the hard coded link never changed, but the basic files it links to now have.

The site was now back up, thank god! I then logged into the Wordpress admin panel and updated my version of Wordpress, as to be honest it had been a while and it was a little out of date, so a likely culprit for the cause of the error. Once updated, I then went back into the FTP window, renamed the folder back to 'default', and then removed the 'x' character from the end of the actual theme folder that I wanted to use. And ta dah, it now works beautifully with the theme I wanted! Without any fancy code changes or messing around with reinstalling or removing etc. BOSH!!

Hope this helps a few people out. (obviously it's different strokes for different folks)

Answer (score 0):

To get this out of comments --- this is a community wiki answer.

Are your two servers running on the same platform (Linux? Win?) or different ones?

Do you have the same collection of plugins on both platforms?

Here are some things to try.

1. do View Source on your white screen of death and see if there's anything in the source view that can help you diagnose your problem.
2. deactivate all your plugins, then try the theme.
3. if it doesn't work, then this theme is broken on this server setup.
4. reactivate the plugins one by one. One of them will probably give you the white screen of death. Then you know that plugin is incompatible with that theme.